# Type families in Persistent library

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

When explaining the template expansion in the chapter on Persistent, the Yesod book has something looking like

```
newtype Key Person = PersonKey (BackendKey SqlBackend)
```

I'm not quite sure how to read this newtype declaration: is
`PersonKey a` something already defined somewhere else (couldn't
find its definition though) or is `PersonKey` just an ordinary
type or value constructor like `Just`/`Nothing`/`Left`/etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, to simplify just a bit first, let's pretend it said:

```
newtype KeyPerson = PersonKey (BackendKey SqlBackend)
```

In this case, `KeyPerson` would be the "type constructor", and `PersonKey` would be the "data constructor." We would be creating both of them here. The `PersonKey` data constructor would hold a value of type `BackendKey SqlBackend`, which would need to exist elsewhere and be referenced from here.

In this case, we're usually associated types (aka type families), which makes things *slightly* more complicated: `newtype Key Person` means "we're defining an associated `Key` for the `Person` type. But we're still creating a `PersonKey` data constructor just as before.

Comment: Answer copied from a email sent by Michael Snoyman with his permission